# Using PDFs as vector-like images in iOS apps, keeping transparency?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, vector-graphics

I've recently came across a blog post about how you can use Photoshop PDF files as vector images: http://mattgemmell.com/2012/02/10/using-pdf-images-in-ios-apps/

Basically you can achieve quality scalability and I guess save on file size.

However, compressing into a PDF as opposed to PNG seems to kill transparency, meaning you get a white background by default.

This seems like an interesting technique, but it would be far more useful if we the PDFs could somehow retain transparent parts like PNGs do. Does anyone have any ideas or techniques on how this effect could further be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Could you share a sample code for this? I'm working on a similar problem, I'm not able to save pdf with transparent background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PDF's rendered by iOS maintain transparency. Including the code you refer to will retain transparency.

If you are seeing white, make sure:

- Your PDF is saved with transparency.
- In that library you haven't set the backgroundColor (the default is [UIColor clearColor])

Comment: You're correct, I have no idea this didn't work the first time I tried it. Thanks